# Windriver compiler linker file regex

Tags: c, compilation, linker

is there a way to use regex to add all C object files starting with `foo` for example to the linker file `bss` section with Windriver compiler instead of adding them manually one by one

```
SECTIONS {
      outputa 0x10000 :
        {
        foo1.o (.bss)
        foo2.o (.bss)
        ......
        foon.o (.bss)
        }
```

**Imagined solution**

```
SECTIONS {
          outputa 0x10000 :
            {
            foo*.o (.bss)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use regex in linker script.
    GROUP : {
        .sectionname:{"foo*"(.bss) }
....
}